# Stripe Payments requires Bearer Header but I put it and it's not working

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I made a React app and I have some payments integrated. In test mode I'm trying to submit a payment but I always get the authenticate error

```
Error StripeAuthenticationError: You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'). See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/.
    at res.toJSON.then.Error_1.StripeAPIError.message (C:\Users\onaca\Desktop\Projects\vTrails\server\node_modules\stripe\lib\RequestSender.js:96:31)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  type: 'StripeAuthenticationError',
  raw: {
    message: "You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'). See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/.",
    type: 'invalid_request_error',
    headers: {
      server: 'nginx',
      date: 'Wed, 15 Mar 2023 20:23:01 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'content-length': '342',
      connection: 'keep-alive',
      'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
      'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
      'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
      'access-control-max-age': '300',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
      'www-authenticate': 'Basic realm="Stripe"',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'
    },
    statusCode: 401,
    requestId: undefined
  },
  rawType: 'invalid_request_error',
  code: undefined,
  doc_url: undefined,
  param: undefined,
  detail: undefined,
  headers: {
    server: 'nginx',
    date: 'Wed, 15 Mar 2023 20:23:01 GMT',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'content-length': '342',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
    'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
    'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
    'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
    'access-control-max-age': '300',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
    'www-authenticate': 'Basic realm="Stripe"',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'
  },
  requestId: undefined,
  statusCode: 401,
  charge: undefined,
  decline_code: undefined,
  payment_intent: undefined,
  payment_method: undefined,
  payment_method_type: undefined,
  setup_intent: undefined,
  source: undefined
}
```

But when I sent the request from the frontend, I did include that.
This is my code on frontend

```
function PaymentForm ({formData, setFormData, setIsLoading}) {
  const stripe = useStripe()
  const elements = useElements()
  const API = axios.create({baseURL:'http://localhost:3500'});

API.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
    
        req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${ct.SECRET_KEY}`
    
    return req;
    
})
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const {error, paymentMethod} = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
        type: "card",
        card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
    })


if(!error) {
    try {
        setIsLoading(true)
        const {id} = paymentMethod
        const response = await API.post("http://localhost:3500/payment", {
            amount: 1000,
            id,
            description:'Advertising Purchase'
        })

        if(response.data.success) {
            console.log("Successful payment")
            setFormData({...formData, paid: true})
            setIsLoading(false)
        }

    } catch (error) {
       setIsLoading(false)
        alert(error)
    }
} else {
    console.log(error.message)
}
}

return (
    <>
    {!formData.paid ? 
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={{marginTop:'2rem', textAlign:'center'}}>
        <fieldset className="FormGroup">
            <div className="FormRow">
                <CardElement options={CARD_OPTIONS}/>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <Button type='submit' variant='contained'>PAY ${Number(formData.price)/100 * 5}</Button>
    </form>
    :
   <div>
       <h2>You just bought a sweet spatula congrats this is the best decision of you're life</h2>
   </div> 
    }
        
    </>
)
}
```

and this is what I have on my backend

```
app.post("/payment", cors(), async (req, res) => {
    let { amount, id, description } = req.body
    try {
        const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount,
            currency: "USD",
            description: description,
            payment_method: id,
            confirm: true
        })
        console.log("Payment", payment)
        res.json({
            message: "Payment successful",
            success: true
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error", error)
        res.json({
            message: "Payment failed",
            success: false
        })
    }
})
```

It is just a basic payment from Stripe docs. Should I add a middleware to the route somehow? Or I don't know.. on the frontend side I added the Authorization Header and in the be I didn't have the authorization header added, so I added it and then it kept tell me same, and I have no further ideas.
Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're setting up `API` using Axios to talk to your own API/backend. If `ct.SECRET_KEY` is your Stripe secret key, you should not be using this in any client-side code, and it's not clear why you'd set this header when communicating with your own backend.

In your backend endpoint, how are you initializing `stripe`? Your secret key should be provided when initialized `stripe-node` as [documented](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/README.md#usage):

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_...');
```

Where in your code is the error coming from? Which call exactly?

Comment: import Stripe from 'stripe'
const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_TEST) - This is how I initialize it, and honestly I don't know why I used my secret in the client, I know it is now right.

Comment: I don't have any errors with my code, it says that error occurs \server\node_modules\stripe\lib\RequestSender.js:96:31) here

Comment: Where does that bubble up within your own code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your app with `StripeProvider`, and then add Stipe public key to it. Below is an example:

```
<StripeProvider publishableKey={"ADD_YOUR_PK_HERE"} merchantIdentifier={"ADD_YOUR_MERCHANT_ID_HERE"}>
     <App />
</StripeProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Dot-env before initialising Stripe, inspite of the fact you used it on server.js/main.js file or not.
It will resolve this error.
Here is sample for your refrence:

```js
import stripe from "stripe";
// to resolve stripe secret key error again use dotenv here
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
const stripeInstance = stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
```